# Submit button clicking changing the value of it to another thing

Tags: php, javascript

maybe very easy!
I'm php coder and I don't have experience in js but I must do this for one of my codes 
suppose I have sub1 in page after clicking it must be that sub1 but value now is sub2

```
       <html>
        <head>
        <title>pharmacy</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <form method="post" action="pharmacy.php">
        <?php
       //some code
            if(array_key_exists('update',$_POST)){
                //somecode
                }
        ?>
<input type="submit" name="update" value="<?php echo if(isset($_GET['update'])) ? 'Show' : 'Update' ?> ">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`show` as function name does not really make sense here (imo), but you could do:

```
<input type="submit" name="sub" value="sub1" onclick="show(this)">
```

and

```
function show(element) {
    element.value = 'sub2';
}
```

---

**Important:**

But that will actually not solve your problem. As soon as you click the button, the form is submitted, meaning the browser initiates a new request and will **load a new page**. So every change you made the current page is lost anyway.

The question is: What are you trying to do?

It seems to me that you should change the value of the button on the server side. You have to keep track which form was submitted (or how often, I don't know what you are trying to do) and set the value of the button accordingly.

**Update:**

I see several possibilities to solve this:

1. You could keep using JavaScript and send and get the data via [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). As you have no experience with JavaScript, I would say you have to learn more about JavaScript and Ajax first before you can use it.
2. You could add a GET parameter in your URL with which you can know which label to show for the button. Example:

   ```
   <form method="post" action="?update=1">
   ```

   and

   ```
   <input type="submit" name="sub" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['update']) ? 'Show' : 'Update' ?> ">
   ```
3. Similar to 2, but use a [session variable](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) (and not a GET parameter) to keep track of the state.

**Update2:**

As you are already having `$_POST['update']` you don't need the URL parameter. It could just  be:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>pharmacy</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="pharmacy.php">
        <input type="submit" name="update" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['update']) ? 'Update' : 'Show'; ?> ">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Negin: That is what I was just writing in my answer. If you submit the form, a new page will be loaded.

Comment: Felix I had a problem in one of my codes it was about a list when I first time click it it shows me the list and second time when i click it it shows me the updated ones the reason is there: I want to put the value:the list for the first time and after showing show me:Update

Comment: @Negin: It is not a problem with your code, it is how form submission works. When you submit a form, the browser loads a **new page** (it is like typing a new URL in the address bar). Changes you make with JavaScript are only for the **current** page.  You cannot solve this with JavaScript (you could use Ajax, but I think this is a bit too advanced). As you know PHP, I would solve this problem at the server side.

Comment: I questioned it 1 hour ago and I used the solution:

Comment: here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225251/submit-button-will-not-show-the-result-by-one-click-it-will-show-it-by-second-cli

Comment: my problem was solved there but another problem(that i told) comes!

Comment: @Negin: Please see my update. Also note that your HTML is incorrect. HTML content has to come between the `body` tags: `<html><head></head><body>... conteent here...</body></html>`. This could also create problems.

Comment: @Negin: I'm sorry but your code seems very complex and unorganized. It would take some time to go through it. Point 2 and 3 in my answer should give you the right idea.

Comment: @Negin: [It is the URL where the data of the form should be sent to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/form#attr-action). If you don't define it, it will be sent to the same URL. I'm not even sure if this works this way, you might have to write `action="pageName.php?update=1"`. But after seeing that you use sessions, I suggest you go with that.

Comment: @Negin: Yep, it misses a closing bracket (or there is a bracket too much). Fixed.

Comment: i think i must write if before isset yes?

Comment: @Negin: See my update. `if` is wrong here, as this is the *ternary operator*: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: :D I LOVE YOU! THANK You very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script>
function show()
{
    document.getElementById("sub").value= "sub2";
            return true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post">
<input type='submit' id="sub" name='sub' value="sub1" onclick="return show()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `input` element has no `id`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
        function show(){
        document.getElementsByName('sub')[0].value = 'sub2';
        return false;
        }
```

**Edit:** if you don't want it to submit the form, just add a `return false`, but then you'd need to change your `onclick` from your submit button to your forms `onsubmit`;

Comment: it has that problem like Felix just for a short time!

Comment: Niklas it can't go to if(array_key_exists) when I added the script why?

Comment: Niklas it will not show my changed value when I used onsubmit